# Laravel4 - @include() includes only one page

Tags: include, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a view for each page, like this:

```
<!-- {pagename}.blade.php --!>

@extends((($nolayout == true) ? 'layouts.plain' : 'layouts.base'))

@section('title')
    <title><!-- some title here --!></title>
@stop

@section('content')

<section class="container clearfix">

    <!-- some content here --!>

</section>

@stop
```

I have my plain.blade.php file which contains only this:

```
@yield('content')
```

And a base.blade.php file which also contains some wrapping tags, but that's not relevant here.

When I try to append the views to my home view, like this:

```
@include('about', array('nolayout' => true))
@include('offer', array('nolayout' => true))
@include('contact', array('nolayout' => true))
```

It appends just the first view multiple times (in this case it would be 'about' included 3 times). Each of these views can be included alone and work fine, but when I stack them, whichever first one I call gets repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Sections that contain content will be yielded if requested to do so. As parents are rendered before children in most cases, you will get the same data over and over. As sections, in essence, populate containers, the 'content' container in this instance is populated with data on your first `@include`. When it is extended a second and third time it is instantly asked to yield the content, despite the child effectively saying, overwrite that section with x amount of content.

I'm not 100% sure of the purpose of a plain.blade layout file if all it does is yield a section. You would be better off having a base section in your master layout titled section that doesn't yield. Each include should then call the `@parent` blade method to append it's data to the already populated section and then yield once it is ready.

**Example from comments**

Where you have `@yield` in your layout, try

```
@section('content')
    {{-- Parent Content --}}
@stop
```

In your child views

```
@section('content')
    @parent
    {{-- Content to append --}}
@stop
```

Then in your rendering view

```
@include('about', array(...))
@include('another', array(...))

@yield('content')
```

Comment: The purpose of it all is to be able to render each page as a standalone or just include the bare content without surrounding tags like html, body, title, etc. Either for stacking into one page layout or using via AJAX. I had problems using any other solution for that, thus the plain.blade layout.

Comment: Did you try removing the `@yield` and replace with a `@section .. @stop` section. Then yielding that after your content has been written to the section?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean.